# How to split into columns the count of a categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

```
I have a *DataFrame* like that: 


ID_client l   date  l   contact
--------------------------------------
1          2017/01/01      email
1          2017/01/02      mail
1          2017/01/03      email
1          .........
1          2017/06/06      sms 
2          ......          tel 
2                          tel 
3
.
etc      until 2017/31/31 etc
```

and I would like to have 2 DataFrames, the first only one line for year with the sum of each contact split in different columns and the last same per month:

1)

```
id l email l sms l tel l mail
----------------------------
1    40       20   30    50
2    20       30    40   50 
2  ........................
3 ..............etc
```

2)

```
id l date_month l email l sms l tel l email
--------------------------------------------------
1    2017/01      20       10    5    2
1    2017/02      ..............
.
2    2017/01   .............
2    2017/02  ................
.
etc
```

I tried

```
Df.set_index("date")
Df["contact"].resample("m")
Df.groupby(df["date", "I'd_client"])["contact"].Count() 
Df.groupby(df["date", "I'd_client"]). Agg({"contact" :" count"})
```

Or I tried to create another *dataframe*

```
df2=Df.groupby(df.index)
Df2=[["contact"]]
df2.apply(lambda x : x.count())
```

But it didnt give me what I wanted!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['date l'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date l'])

df1 = df.groupby(['ID_client l','contact']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
contact      email  mail  sms  tel
ID_client l                       
1                2     1    1    0
2                0     0    0    2

df11 = (df.groupby(['ID_client l', df['date l'].dt.year,'contact'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df11)
contact  ID_client l  date l  email  mail  sms  tel
0                  1    2017      2     1    1    0
1                  2    2017      0     0    0    2
```

---

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['ID_client l', df['date l'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m'),'contact'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
contact  ID_client l   date l  email  mail  sms  tel
0                  1  2017/01      2     1    0    0
1                  1  2017/06      0     0    1    0
2                  2  2017/06      0     0    0    2
```